# how to push objects into array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following situation. I am fetching data from the backend and the response is a bunch of objects. I want to iterate into them and in every iteration, I want to push them into my state.

here is how I am getting data from the backend:

```
     const allBookings = useSelector(getBookings);

      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(
          fetchBookings.request({
            getAll: true,
          })
        );
      }, [dispatch]);
```

here is my data:

```
bookings:{
  0:{id: 294, address: '1585 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'aaa'}},
  1:{id: 294, address: '1586 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'bbb'}},
  2:{id: 294, address: '1587 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'ccc'}}
}
```

Here where I am trying to set my data in an array, but something goes wrong, please help me to figure out how I can achieve. The final result should be like this:

```
    [
      {id: 294, address: '1585 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'aaa'}},
      {id: 294, address: '1586 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'bbb'}},
      {id: 294, address: '1587 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'ccc'}}
    ]
```

```
     if (!allBookings) return null;

      const book = allBookings.bookings;
      const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (book) {
          const x = Object.entries(book);
          setBooks(x);
        }
      }, [book]);

    console.log('books===>', books);
```

[here is my code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-water-0q0z9)

Comment: Since you already have `allBookings` why add the same entries in local state ? You can use the `allBookings` directly. Additionally you cannot use hooks conditionally, meaning that you cannot have a branch like `if (..) return null;` and then add a `useXXX` hook after that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `const x = Object.entries(book)`; to `const x = Object.values(book);`

Answer (score 2):

Use functional update to push new entires into your `books` array:

```
const x = Object.entries(book);
setBooks(books => [...books, ...x]);
```

Since you’re always instantiating with an empty array you also don’t need the falsy check, ie you can remove `if (books)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `useEffect` use the store selector var to watch changes ,

also you shouldn't use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in your case , instead use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) ,

Object.entries will get both key and values , and put them as an array for each entry like

```
[["0",{id: 294, address: '1585 Charleston Rd,...}]]
```

but `Object.values` wil only create new array from values ( your objects )

your code should looks like

```
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (allBookings.bookings) {
      const entries = Object.values(allBookings.bookings);
      setBooks(entries);
    }
  }, [allBookings]);
```

Try the below Snippet  :

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
   let serverObject = {
    bookings:{
      0:{id: 294, address: '1585 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'aaa'}},
      1:{id: 294, address: '1586 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'bbb'}},
      2:{id: 294, address: '1587 Charleston Rd, Mountain View, CA, USA', broker:{name:'ccc'}}
    }
  }
  
  const [allBookings, setAllBookings] = useState({});
  
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  
  setTimeout(()=> { setAllBookings(serverObject)},  2000)
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (allBookings.bookings) {
      const entries = Object.values(allBookings.bookings);
      setBooks(entries);
    }
  }, [allBookings]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
         books.map( book => <p> {book.address} </p>)
      }
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.values` instead of `Object.entries`.

Also, merge new res with the previous res.

```
const data = Object.entries(book);
setBooks(books => [...books, ...data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Never recommended to mutate the state directly.

The recommended approach in later React versions is to use an updater function when modifying states to prevent race conditions:

**For Functional Components**

```
const [array,setArray] = useState([]);
```

Push value at the end:

```
setArray(oldArray => [...oldArray,newValue] );
```

Push value at the beginning:

```
setArray(oldArray => [newValue,...oldArray] );
```

**For Class Components**

Push string to end of the array, you do this...

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myArray: [...prevState.myArray, "new value"]
}))
```

Push string to beginning of the array, you do it like this ...

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myArray: ["new value", ...prevState.myArray]
}))
```

Push object to end of the array, you do this ...

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myArray: [...prevState.myArray, {"name": "object"}]
}))
```

Push object to beginning of the array, you do this ....

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  myArray: [ {"name": "object"}, ...prevState.myArray]
}))
```